# Allow for divide by zero to = zero

Tags: divide

I know that you cannot divide anything by zero.

But, is it possible to have visual studio to give a result of zero if any arithmetic operation attempts to divide by zero?

if so, how?

for this particular project, it would actually save me a lot of work and code if I could allow anything that is / 0 = 0

I am looking to have the result of an integer divided by zero to equal zero.  VB.NET Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: yes, you will have to create your own divide function and use that one instead of /

Comment: What language? Integers, floating point values, or something else?

Comment: you will need to use an `if` function,

Comment: Visual Basic / Visual Studio 2010 - dividing integers by 0

Comment: While I could use the IF statement, I would have to do it in hundreds of places now.

Ideally, I would like to see a result of zero everywhere that I attempt to divide by zero with a little code as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is simply by checking the divisor of the division with an if statement. You can decide to perform the division if the divisor is not 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try Catch

Catch the exception Divide By Zero

Do as you will.

Comment: It will do (maybe, not if it's just a part of a term), but it's not intended to be used like that, bad performance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using if in a static method if you want to access it in all computation?

**C#/Java code**

```
public static int myDivision(int dividend, int divisor)
{
    //return is the answer

    if(divisor == 0)
    { return 0; }
    else
    { return dividend/divisor; }

    //just do something like this
}
```

or for something clearer

```
public static int myDivision(int dividend, int divisor)
{
    int quotient = 0;

    if(divisor == 0)
    { return quotient; }
    else
    { 
      quotient = dividend/divisor;
      return quotient; 
    }

    //just do something like this
}
```

//note: you may also use it through an object method